# Hive Error : Task has been rejected by ExecutorService

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using `Hive_2.1.1` with `Hadoop 2.7`.

I am trying to write to hive from a simple Java program. I first read the metadata of the table that is there on Hive. 
I am getting the following error.

> WARN server.TThreadPoolServer: Task has been rejected by
>   ExecutorService 9 times till timedout, reason:
>   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecution Exception: Task
>   org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess@1358b6e 6
>   rejected from
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThreadPoolExecutorWithOomHook
>   @254fbff6[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks =
>   0, completed tasks = 3]

Any configuration settings needed in `hive_site.xml` to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below in hive-site.xml

```
  <property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.max.worker.threads</name>
  <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.min.worker.threads</name>
  <value>1</value>
  </property>
```